# How to add the values of all the fields in a struct in matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct, sum, addition

I have a struct lets say `ABC` with dimension "1*100" struct and it has a field called `EFG` which holds a value of `1.6` each.

I need to get `1.6+1.6+1.6+.......+1.6` 100 times by using MATLAB.

I tried using `sum`but it doesn't suit for this. How can this be done?

```
Sum(ABC(:).EFG)
sum(ABC(:).EFG,2)
```

These did not work

Comment: You're saying `ABC` holds 100 structures, each one having a field called `EFG` is that correct? Better yet, can you provide the code to create ABC?

Comment: no i meant ABC Holding 100 of 1*1 structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need brackets:

```
for ii = 1:100         % Just creating the struct
   ABC(ii).EFG = 1.6;  % 1x100 struct with the field EFG
end

sum([ABC(:).EFG])
ans =
  160.0000
```

Notice the brackets around `[ABC(:).EFG]`.

The reason is because without it you get an output from `ABC(:).EFG` that can't be used in `sum`:

```
ABC(:).EFG
ans =
    1.6000
ans =
    1.6000
ans =
    1.6000
ans =
    1.6000
ans =
    1.6000
```

Concatenate it, and you'll get something you can use:

```
[ABC(:).EFG]
ans =
    1.6000    1.6000    1.6000    1.6000    1.6000
```